# How to start a paragraph from the middle in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. **Likewise how can I do that in HTML?** I can use that **&nbsp** to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to add in every paras. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:first-letter` pseudo element

Something like

```
p:first-letter {
    padding-left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: is it good way to give that much padding? sorry for asking.

Comment: @Leothelion The OP wants "the middle" which is usually pretty accurately 50%

Comment: yes i know that by padding-left:50%, content will be in middle but i read some where that you should not give too much padding or margin so just asking is this good practise or not..just for my knowledge..nothing else..

Comment: Seems that's working. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cagqsw8x/)

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%
} /* to position paragraph vertically*/

p:first-letter {
    padding-left:50%
}/* to position first line horizontally */


<p>I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.I want to start a paragraph from the middle of the page. For an example when we look a novel, its' paragraphs are always starting from the middle of its pages. Likewise how can I do that in HTML? I can use " " to make spaces. But I think it is not practical to do in every paras. Thank you.</p>
```

Comment: You can use text-indent property for starting the paragraph from the middle of the page. 
p{
text-indent: 50%:
}